References in template of applied mathematics letters
I dont understand the template of applied mathematics letters. I downloaded the template in https://assets.ctfassets.net/o78em1y1w4i4/5uFmLZJTPDMAUjFnHRpjj8/6f19a979146eb93263763d87a894ab0d/els-cas-templates.zip
The file cas-sc-template.tex is
%% 
%% Copyright 2019-2024 Elsevier Ltd
%% 
%% This file is part of the 'CAS Bundle'.
%% --------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'CAS Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%% 
%% Template article for cas-sc documentclass for 
%% double column output.

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

% If the frontmatter runs over more than one page
% use the longmktitle option.

%\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-sc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

%%%Author macros
\def\tsc#1{\csdef{#1}{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}\xspace}}
\tsc{WGM}
\tsc{QE}
%%%

% Uncomment and use as if needed
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
%\newdefinition{rmk}{Remark}
%\newproof{pf}{Proof}
%\newproof{pot}{Proof of Theorem \ref{thm}}

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}

% Short title
\shorttitle{}    

% Short author
\shortauthors{}  

% Main title of the paper
\title [mode = title]{}  

% Title footnote mark
% eg: \tnotemark[1]
\tnotemark[1] 

% Title footnote 1.
% eg: \tnotetext[1]{Title footnote text}
\tnotetext[1]{} 

% First author
%
% Options: Use if required
% eg: \author[1,3]{Author Name}[type=editor,
%       style=chinese,
%       auid=000,
%       bioid=1,
%       prefix=Sir,
%       orcid=0000-0000-0000-0000,
%       facebook=<facebook id>,
%       twitter=<twitter id>,
%       linkedin=<linkedin id>,
%       gplus=<gplus id>]

\author[1]{}%[<options>]

% Corresponding author indication
\cormark[1]

% Footnote of the first author
\fnmark[1]

% Email id of the first author
\ead{}

% URL of the first author
\ead[url]{}

% Credit authorship
% eg: \credit{Conceptualization of this study, Methodology, Software}
\credit{}

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[1]{organization={},
            addressline={}, 
            city={},
%          citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={}, 
            state={},
            country={}}

\author[2]{}%[]

% Footnote of the second author
\fnmark[2]

% Email id of the second author
\ead{}

% URL of the second author
\ead[url]{}

% Credit authorship
\credit{}

% Address/affiliation
\affiliation[2]{organization={},
            addressline={}, 
            city={},
%          citysep={}, % Uncomment if no comma needed between city and postcode
            postcode={}, 
            state={},
            country={}}

% Corresponding author text
\cortext[1]{Corresponding author}

% Footnote text
\fntext[1]{}

% For a title note without a number/mark
%\nonumnote{}

% Here goes the abstract
\begin{abstract}
Here goes the abstract \nocite{*}%% Remove this line from your manuscript.
\end{abstract}

% Use if graphical abstract is present
%\begin{graphicalabstract}
%\includegraphics{}
%\end{graphicalabstract}

% Research highlights
\begin{highlights}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{highlights}


% Keywords
% Each keyword is seperated by \sep
\begin{keywords}
 \sep \sep \sep
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

% Main text
\section{}\label{}

% Numbered list
% Use the style of numbering in square brackets.
% If nothing is used, default style will be taken.
%\begin{enumerate}[a)]
%\item 
%\item 
%\item 
%\end{enumerate}  

% Unnumbered list
%\begin{itemize}
%\item 
%\item 
%\item 
%\end{itemize}  

% Description list
%\begin{description}
%\item[]
%\item[] 
%\item[] 
%\end{description}  

\clearpage %%Remove this from your manuscript


% Figure
\begin{figure}%[]
  \centering
%    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}%[]
\caption{}\label{tbl1}
\begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{}LL@{}}
\toprule
  &  \\ % Table header row
\midrule
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

% Uncomment and use as the case may be
%\begin{theorem} 
%\end{theorem}

% Uncomment and use as the case may be
%\begin{lemma} 
%\end{lemma}

%% The Appendices part is started with the command \appendix;
%% appendix sections are then done as normal sections
%% \appendix

\section{}\label{}

% To print the credit authorship contribution details
\printcredits

%% Loading bibliography style file
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}

% Loading bibliography database
\bibliography{cas-refs}

% Biography
%\bio{}
% Here goes the biography details.
%\endbio

%\bio{pic1}
% Here goes the biography details.
%\endbio

\end{document}



The file cas-refs.bib is
@ARTICLE{Fortunato2010,
  author  = {Fortunato, S.},
  title   = {Community detection in graphs},
  journal = {Phys. Rep.-Rev. Sec. Phys. Lett.}, 
  volume  = {486},
  year    = {2010},
  pages   = {75-174}
}

@ARTICLE{NewmanGirvan2004,
  author  = {Newman, M. E. J. and Girvan, M.},
  title   = {Finding and evaluating community structure in networks},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {69},
  year    = {2004},
  pages   = {026113}
}

@ARTICLE{Vehlowetal2013,
  author  = {Vehlow, C. and Reinhardt, T. and Weiskopf, D.},
  title   = {Visualizing Fuzzy Overlapping Communities in Networks},
  journal = {IEEE Trans. Vis. Comput. Graph.}, 
  volume  = {19},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {2486-2495}
}

@ARTICLE{Raghavanetal2007,
  author  = {Raghavan, U. and Albert, R. and Kumara, S.},
  title   = {Near linear time algorithm to detect community structures in large-scale networks},
  journal = {Phys. Rev E.}, 
  volume  = {76},
  year    = {2007},
  pages   = {036106}
}

@ARTICLE{SubeljBajec2011a,
  author  = {\v{S}ubelj, L. and Bajec, M.},
  title   = {Robust network community detection using balanced propagation},
  journal = {Eur. Phys. J. B.}, 
  volume  = {81},
  year    = {2011},
  pages   = {353-362}
}

@ARTICLE{Louetal2013,
  author  = {Lou, H. and Li, S. and Zhao, Y.},
  title   = {Detecting community structure using label propagation with weighted coherent neighborhood propinquity},
  journal = {Physica A.}, 
  volume  = {392},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {3095-3105}
}

@ARTICLE{Clausetetal2004,
  author  = {Clauset, A. and Newman, M. E. J. and Moore, C.},
  title   = {Finding community structure in very large networks},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {70},
  year    = {2004},
  pages   = {066111}
}

@ARTICLE{Blondeletal2008,
  author  = {Blondel, V. D. and Guillaume, J. L. and Lambiotte, R. and Lefebvre, E.},
  title   = {Fast unfolding of communities in large networks},
  journal = {J. Stat. Mech.-Theory Exp.}, 
  volume  = {2008},
  year    = {2008},
  pages   = {P10008}
}

@ARTICLE{SobolevskyCampari2014,
  author  = {Sobolevsky, S. and Campari, R.},
  title   = {General optimization technique for high-quality community detection in complex networks},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {90},
  year    = {2014},
  pages   = {012811}
}

@ARTICLE{FortunatoBarthelemy2007,
  author  = {Fortunato, S. and Barthelemy, M.},
  title   = {Resolution limit in community detection},
  journal = {Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U. S. A.}, 
  volume  = {104},
  year    = {2007},
  pages   = {36-41}
}

@ARTICLE{SubeljBajec2011b,
  author  = {\v{S}ubelj, L. and Bajec, M.},
  title   = {Unfolding communities in large complex networks: Combining defensive and offensive label propagation for core extraction},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {83},
  year    = {2011},
  pages   = {036103}
}

@ARTICLE{WangLi2013,
  author  = {Wang, X. and Li, J.},
  title   = {Detecting communities by the core-vertex and intimate degree in complex networks},
  journal = {Physica A.}, 
  volume  = {392},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {2555-2563}
}

@ARTICLE{Lietal2013,
  author  = {Li, J. and Wang, X. and Eustace, J.},
  title   = {Detecting overlapping communities by seed community in weighted complex networks},
  journal = {Physica A.}, 
  volume  = {392},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {6125-6134}
}

@ARTICLE{Fabioetal2013,
  author  = {Fabio, D. R. and Fabio, D. and Carlo, P.},
  title   = {Profiling core-periphery network structure by random walkers},
  journal = {Sci. Rep.}, 
  volume  = {3},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {1467}
}

@ARTICLE{Chenetal2013,
  author  = {Chen, Q. and Wu, T. T. and Fang, M.},
  title   = {Detecting local community structure in complex networks based on local degree central nodes},
  journal = {Physica A.}, 
  volume  = {392},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {529-537}
}

@ARTICLE{Zhangetal2007,
  author  = {Zhang, S. and Wang, R. and Zhang, X.},
  title   = {Identification of overlapping community structure in complex networks using fuzzy c-means clustering},
  journal = {Physica A.}, 
  volume  = {374},
  year    = {2007},
  pages   = {483-490}
}

@ARTICLE{Nepuszetal2008,
  author  = {Nepusz, T. and Petr\'oczi, A. and N\'egyessy, L. and Bazs\'o, F.},
  title   = {Fuzzy communities and the concept of bridgeness in complex networks},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {77},
  year    = {2008},
  pages   = {016107}
}

@ARTICLE{FabricioLiang2013,
  author  = {Fabricio, B. and Liang, Z.},
  title   = {Fuzzy community structure detection by particle competition and cooperation},
  journal = {Soft Comput.}, 
  volume  = {17},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {659-673}
}

@ARTICLE{Sunetal2011,
  author  = {Sun, P. and Gao, L. and Han, S.},
  title   = {Identification of overlapping and non-overlapping community structure by fuzzy clustering in complex networks},
  journal = {Inf. Sci.}, 
  volume  = {181},
  year    = {2011},
  pages   = {1060-1071}
}

@ARTICLE{Wangetal2013,
  author  = {Wang, W. and Liu, D. and Liu, X. and Pan, L.},
  title   = {Fuzzy overlapping community detection based on local random walk and multidimensional scaling},
  journal = {Physica A.}, 
  volume  = {392},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {6578-6586}
}

@ARTICLE{Psorakisetal2011,
  author  = {Psorakis, I. and Roberts, S. and Ebden, M. and Sheldon, B.},
  title   = {Overlapping community detection using Bayesian non-negative matrix factorization},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {83},
  year    = {2011},
  pages   = {066114}
}

@CONFERENCE{ZhangYeung2012,
  author  = {Zhang, Y. and Yeung, D.},
  title   = {Overlapping Community Detection via Bounded Nonnegative Matrix Tri-Factorization},
  booktitle = {In Proc. ACM SIGKDD Conf.}, 
  year    = {2012},
  pages   = {606-614}
}

@ARTICLE{Liu2010,
  author  = {Liu, J.},
  title   = {Fuzzy modularity and fuzzy community structure in networks},
  journal = {Eur. Phys. J. B.}, 
  volume  = {77},
  year    = {2010},
  pages   = {547-557}
}

@ARTICLE{Havensetal2013,
  author  = {Havens, T. C. and Bezdek, J. C. and Leckie, C. and Ramamohanarao, K. and Palaniswami, M.},
  title   = {A Soft Modularity Function For Detecting Fuzzy Communities in Social Networks},
  journal = {IEEE Trans. Fuzzy Syst.}, 
  volume  = {21},
  year    = {2013},
  pages   = {1170-1175}
}

@misc{Newman2013,
  author = {Newman, M. E. J.},
  title  = {Network data},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/}",
  year = {2013}
}

@ARTICLE{SubeljBajec2012,
  author  = {\v{S}ubelj, L. and Bajec, M.},
  title   = {Ubiquitousness of link-density and link-pattern communities in real-world networks},
  journal = {Eur. Phys. J. B.}, 
  volume  = {85},
  year    = {2012},
  pages   = {1-11}
}

@ARTICLE{Lancichinettietal2008,
  author  = {Lancichinetti, A. and Fortunato, S. and Radicchi, F.},
  title   = {Benchmark graphs for testing community detection algorithms},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {78},
  year    = {2008},
  pages   = {046110}
}

@ARTICLE{Liuetal2014,
  author  = {Liu, W. and Pellegrini, M. and Wang, X.},
  title   = {Detecting Communities Based on Network Topology},
  journal = {Sci. Rep.}, 
  volume  = {4},
  year    = {2014},
  pages   = {5739}
}

@ARTICLE{Danonetal2005,
  author  = {Danon, L. and Diaz-Guilera, A. and Duch, J. and Arenas, A.},
  title   = {Comparing community structure identification},
  journal = {J. Stat. Mech.-Theory Exp.}, 
  volume  = {},
  year    = {2005},
  pages   = {P09008}
}

@ARTICLE{Gregory2011,
  author  = {Gregory, S.},
  title   = {Fuzzy overlapping communities in networks},
  journal = {J. Stat. Mech.-Theory Exp.}, 
  volume  = {},
  year    = {2011},
  pages   = {P02017}
}

@ARTICLE{LancichinettiFortunato2009,
  author  = {Lancichinetti, A. and Fortunato, S.},
  title   = {Benchmarks for testing community detection algorithms on directed and weighted graphs with overlapping communities},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. E.}, 
  volume  = {80},
  year    = {2009},
  pages   = {016118}
}

@CONFERENCE{HullermeierRifqi2009,
  author  = {Hullermeier, E. and Rifqi, M.},
  title   = {A Fuzzy Variant of the Rand Index for Comparing Clustering Structures},
  booktitle = {in Proc. IFSA/EUSFLAT Conf.}, 
  year    = {2009},
  pages   = {1294-1298}
}



Question. How can I leave the references with numbering by numbers? Something similar to this article
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965924002295/pdfft?md5=add2e9b2cc2b7e10165c84852a6417c2&pid=1-s2.0-S0893965924002295-main.pdf

The template has
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

Just comment out the third line and uncomment the first
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

I reduced your bib file to just the first three entries and tried
\section{Test}\label{a}

\cite{Fortunato2010}

\cite{NewmanGirvan2004,Vehlowetal2013}

\cite{NewmanGirvan2004,Vehlowetal2013,Fortunato2010}

to get, after running LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX,

If you change to
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

you'd get

In either case, the references will be

